# How does my typescript application detect the type definitions of an external package?

Tags: typescript

I have developed a private package (package_a) that includes a list of type definitions in a `index.d.ts` file. When I use this private package in my application (where package_a is installed in the node_modules folder), how does my application detect/use those type definitions?
I'm don't think I need to explicitly import the `index.d.ts` file anywhere, so does TypeScript (and my IDE) automatically pick them up from some global scope, or is it down to package resolution or something similar? It would be good to understand the mechanics of how it is detected.

Comment: [Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html#identifying-kinds-of-libraries)  [Node Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) Based on the things we use in the project it automatically looks for the packages installed in the node_modules folders or they are downloaded as part of the packages sometime and Identifies the Typing's

Comment: If, for example, package_a contains a React component `Button`. Once package_a is built and has been compiled to a single `index.js` file, how does it link the Button  types defined in `index.d.ts` to `Button` when I use `Button` in my application?

Comment: Now the package_a built with (React button) - it has all the typing referenced to the React Lib button as soon as you use it some other place it know where to look for it definition based on the module resolution

Comment: So if `index.d.ts` in package_a has `export { Button } from './components/Buttons/Button/Button';` and in my application I do `import { Button } from 'package_a';`, does it simply match the name `Button`?